# A javascript script to load a list into a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

```
function postFetch(data) {
  let element = document.getElementById('placetoputlist');

  element.innerHTML = "";


  for (let priority of data.priority_list) {

    element.innerHTML += "<h1>" + priority + "</h1>";
    element.innerHTML += "<ul>";
    for (let item of data[priority]) {
      element.innerHTML += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
    }
    element.innerHTML += "</ul>";
  }

}

fetch("test", {cache: "no-cache"}).then(data=>data.json()).then(res=>{postFetch(res)});
```

This is a small script that loads a (list of) list(s) (stored in JSON format in the file `test`) into an element of a HTML page with id "placetoputlist". Is this a good way to achieve this? What can be improved (if any) and what would be better names for `placetoputlist` and `element`?

Comment: I would rename the variables to what they are doing for the business logic, instead of `placetoputlist` i would rename it as `listForTasks` or whatever makes most sense for the task at that, rest pretty much lgtm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of good points to start out:

- You use `for..of` loops... great!
- You use `fetch`... great!

Suggestions for improvement:

#### Naming

JS uses `snakeCase`, not `snake_case`. It's OK to use `snake_case` for response structures that use it as is the case here (you might consider renaming them), but not otherwise.

CSS generally uses `kebab-case`. I'm not sure how to parse `placetoputlist`. Is this "place to put list"? I suggest naming this `output-list`.

Usually, functions should be verbs. `postFetch` seems to be a noun and I'm not sure how its name matches its purpose (POST-ing is an HTTP verb which isn't what the function does). I suggest `appendDataToList` or similar.

#### Use `const`, not `let`

Pretty much the only good thing about `let` is that it saves two bytes and keystrokes. `const` is better on all counts because it provides a stronger invariant, freeing up mental energy to not have to track reassignments for a variable, reducing bugs and making your code more expressive: in the rare times when you *do* choose to use `let` (say, loop counters), it's an explicit statement of intent: "I intend to mutate this variable".

If you're using `let` when there's no mutation, then make it `const`. If you find you're reassigning and mutating frequently, the excessive presence of `let` gives you a handy red flag to create more functions. I like to pretend `let` doesn't exist for the most part, sort of like `var`.

#### Use template strings, not `+`

ES6 offers template strings using the backtick syntax `` `foo${bar}` ``, which are far more elegant than the old days of `"foo" + bar`. If you need this code to be compatible, I suggest using a transpiler so you can write and read modern code.

#### Be careful with `element.innerHTML += ...`

`element.innerHTML` may look like a simple string assignment, but it's not. It does a lot of work under the hood, rebuilding the previous nodes (which destroys their event listeners), parsing nodes from the string you appended and basically rebuilding the whole child tree. It's like [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) but with a ton of extra overhead.

There are two general options:

1. Build your string in a normal variable and make a single call to `.innerHTML = ...` so the work to build the DOM tree is done once.
2. Create nodes using `document.createElement("li")` and call functions in the `.appendChild` family to add them to other nodes. This may be more efficient than `.innerHTML`, but you'd need to benchmark to be sure. Template literals are quite elegant and [if the algorithm is fast enough for your app's needs, it's not a performance problem](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

If templating is everywhere in your app and is leading to bugs (remember: template literals don't sanitize data!) and verbosity, you might want to write some of your own abstractions or look into lightweight templating libraries like [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm) in lieu of prematurely adopting the latest trendy UI framework for what might be a simple project.

#### Put chained functions on new lines

The line

```js
fetch("test", {cache: "no-cache"}).then(data=>data.json()).then(res=>{postFetch(res)});
```

is too long and has smushed whitespace. This is easier to read:

```js
fetch("test", {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(res => {
    postFetch(res)
  })
;
```

Most autoformatters, such as the one bundled into [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), do this sort of thing for you.

Since `postFetch` takes one argument and `then`'s callback has one argument, you can remove the extra arrow function wrapper:

```js
fetch("test", {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(postFetch)
;
```

`async`/`await` is worth mentioning, but I don't mind `then` here too much.

#### Check the HTTP response status and handle errors

There's also a naming problem in the `fetch` chain: `data` is actually a `response` and `res` is actually `data` (the parsed JSON body). Switch those two around.

HTTP requests can fail, which means `data.json()` (really `response.json()`) can throw, but there's no `.catch` block, meaning you'll create an uncaught promise rejection error and the application won't provide a sensible notice to the user, or even to the console.

No matter how confident you are in your `fetch` call, I recommend this bare minimum setup:

```js
fetch("test", {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }

    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => { /* consume the data */ })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

If you don't like the verbosity, you can write a wrapper function.

#### Suggested rewrite

Here's a quick rewrite. I don't really know what your response format looks like, and it strikes me as a bit of an odd format (not that that's uncommon for third-party APIs), so take it with a pinch of salt if I've bungled it.

```js
// mocked fetch call for demonstration purposes
window.fetch = async () => ({
  ok: true,
  json: async () => ({
    priority_list: ["low", "med", "high"],
    low: ["a", "b"],
    med: ["x", "y", "z"],
    high: ["l", "m", "n"],
  })
});

const makePriorityNode = (priority, items) => `
  <h1>${priority}</h1>
  <ul>${items.map(e => `<li>${e}</li>`).join("")}</ul>
`;

const appendDataToList = data => {
  const container = document.querySelector(".output-list");
  container.innerHTML = data.priority_list
    .map(e => makePriorityNode(e, data[e]))
    .join("")
  ;
};
  
fetch("test", {cache: "no-cache"})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }

    return response.json();
  })
  .then(appendDataToList)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

```html
<div class="output-list"></div>
```